# Type 2 Effective Dated Index Performance with Multiple Dimensions in TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, indexing

How do composite indices work on effective dated tables?

Utilizing T-SQL, let's say I have a table that is effective dated with an EffectiveStartDate and EffectiveEndDate associated with a product to record historic price fluctuations so my table would take the form:

MyTable := (EffStartDate date, EffEndDate date, ProductID int, ProductPrice money) 
where EffEndDate = '12/31/9999' when the record is valid presently.

Let's further assume I implement two indices on this table in the form:
Clustered on (EffEndDate, EffStartDate, ProductID)
Nonclustered on (EffEndDate, ProductID)

From my understanding, the index creation for clustered indices stores the information in a B-tree (potentially B+) ordered by the column specification order of the index creation statement.  Therefore, I envision the table sorting on EffEndDate, then EffStartDate, then ProductID.  Most of the time I want to query historically out of this table with a query similar to this:
select *
from MyTable
where ProductID = @ProductID
and @MyDate between EffStartDate and EffEndDate.

I am trying to visualize how the B-tree actually stores the information related to these three columns.  Does it store it as a tuple object like you could find in Python, or does it add more dimensions to the B tree when the index is composite?  For instance, for a given EffEndDate does the B-tree have multiple splitting trees relating to EffStartDates and then multiple splitting trees relating to ProductIDs or is each split based on a tuple?  This response seems to believe it takes the tuple approach:
[Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648217/what-does-a-b-tree-index-on-more-than-1-column-look-like).

If it takes the single dimension approach, I find it difficult to conceptualize how these types of indices provide holistic value for the date range look-up between two columns.  For instances, I see it as happening such that, given a date (@MyDate), we can use the EffEndDate component of the index to limit our search to only EffEndDates >= @MyDate, then use the EffStartDate component to limit our search to only EffStartDate <= @MyDate, and then search for the ProductID within this remaining range.  Is this how the index would be used?

The problem I foresee with this is that, if we have about 100k products that get updated non-uniformly every week, we would end up utilizing this clustered index to generate a giant set of capable date ranges, and then would have to search each date range for an instance of our desired ProductID.  Is there a better index to implement on this type of query?

I believe the nonclustered index exists to quickly search out current ProductID prices as we only need two pieces of the puzzle for this since EffEndDate would be set to '12/31/9999'.

Alternatively, is there a way to implement a multidimensional index spanning two columns to improve query performance in T-SQL?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an application that really calls for a 2D, or spatial, index, as you correctly note, since you are effectively composing two separate inequality searches together.  Without jamming your tables into a form where you can use SQL Server's spatial indexes, your options are limited.

The best approach, if it's possible, is to find some sort of business relationship between EffStartDate and EffEndDate.  If there is a rule that these values can't be farther apart than a year, for example, then this is something that could be coded in to your WHERE clause to give you additional selectivity on the indexes you might otherwise take large scans over.

Something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE @date BETWEEN EffStartDate and EffEndDate
    AND DATEADD(year, -1, @date) < EffStartDate
```

...where you are adding an additional business constraint to reduce the search space the query needs to traverse.

Two articles that might be of interest to you are these:

[Quassnoi's answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232770/fastest-way-for-this-query-what-is-the-best-strategy-given-a-date-range), which talks about how to force-fit this type of data into a format that can be spatially indexed, and also has a link to his blog that details a recursive CTE method that can be used to accelerate these types of queries without schema modification.

[Michael Asher's article](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2014/2d-range-query/2/) on using business knowledge to boost performance over similar types of queries.

Comment: Thank you for these links and for highlighting that the B-tree is not going to be able to cut it for a spatial join.  I'm going to attempt to implement a test solution which forces the date ranges into a spatially compatible data type and then compare than performance with the B-tree indices suggested by the other users.  I chose this as the most useful answer because it highlighted the multidimensional approach opposed to a more effective composite one dimensional implementation. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There is no LoanID in the table
I assume you mean ProductID

If you are going to search on ProductID = @ProductID then why in the world would you bury that as the tail end of a composite index.   Why would you do the easy stuff last?

100K updates a week is nothing.  You are over thinking this.  Just put an index on each column and let the query optimizer do what it does.

If you are set on a composite index then ProductID, EffStartDate date, EffEndDate date.
You don't get better than an index seek!
[image]

Comment: Yes, I meant ProductID - thank you.  I had multiple example tables I was working with and evidently couldn't keep them straight.

Comment: Didn't realize shift+enter was a new line. Here is the rest of my thought:
My original thought concerning why one would bury the ProductID at the end of the composite index was the same as yours, but this is an implementation which I saw in the wild recently.  That got me to thinking about how the data was stored and accessed by the B-tree composite index behind the scenes, and my inability to understand the (EffEndDate, EffStartDate, ProductID) composite order's advantage prompted me to post this question.  Thanks!

Comment: @Blam, oh, I see you've posted a screenshot of the `index seek` operator details. You can see that there is `Seek predicate` and `Predicate`. `Seek predicate` is used to do the fast search in the index tree. `Predicate` is evaluation of any other extra conditions that are needed - for each found row. So, if conditions in `seek predicate` (`fieldID = 117 AND value > '1901-01-01'`) result in NNN rows, then condition in `Predicate` would be evaluated NNN times. Having `value2` as a part of the index would not reduce this amount of processed rows.

Answer (score 1):

Simulate the real data. Generate large table (the size of the final table should be the same as you expect in real life) with distribution of products and dates as you'd expect in real life. Start with adding three separate independent indexes on products, start date, end date. Try to run the query. Analyze the execution plan. Try other combinations of indexes. Compare plans and performance. If nothing gives acceptable performance, return here with a script that generates sample data and your query.

In my test the optimizer was inner joining results of three independent index seeks.

**Create table**

plus three independent indexes for each column:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ProductID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [StartDate] [date] NOT NULL,
    [EndDate] [date] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Test] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_EndDate] ON [dbo].[Test] 
(
    [EndDate] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ProductID] ON [dbo].[Test] 
(
    [ProductID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_StartDate] ON [dbo].[Test] 
(
    [StartDate] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

**Generate test data**

- 1M rows in total.
- Up to 100 different product IDs with uniform distribution.
- Start dates are within 10,000 days from 2000-01-01 (~27 years time span)
- End dates are within 1000 days from the start date (duration up to ~3 years)

query:

```
INSERT INTO Test(ProductID, StartDate, EndDate)
SELECT TOP(1000000)
    CA.ProductID
    ,DATEADD(day, StartOffset, '2000-01-01') AS StartDate
    ,DATEADD(day, StartOffset+DurationDays, '2000-01-01') AS EndDate
FROM
sys.all_objects AS o1
cross join sys.all_objects AS o2
cross apply
(
    SELECT
        cast((cast(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(4) as int) / 4294967295.0 + 0.5) * 100 + 1 as int) AS ProductID
        ,cast((cast(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(4) as int) / 4294967295.0 + 0.5) * 10000 as int) AS StartOffset
        ,cast((cast(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(4) as int) / 4294967295.0 + 0.5) * 1000 as int) AS DurationDays
) AS CA
```

The query to optimize:

```
DECLARE @VarDate date = '2004-01-01';
SELECT *
FROM Test
WHERE 
    ProductID = 1
    AND @VarDate >= StartDate
    AND @VarDate <= EndDate
;
```

It returns ~500 rows.

**Execution plan**

[image: plan]

The server suggested the following index:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [<Name of Missing Index, sysname,>]
ON [dbo].[Test] ([ProductID],[StartDate],[EndDate])
INCLUDE ([ID])
```

but having such index is silly, IMHO.

If you had 1M rows in total and 100K different product IDs, rather than 100; in other words, if searching by specific product ID eliminates vast majority of rows, then the best option is likely to have one index on ProductID and include other columns into it:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Product
ON [dbo].[Test] ([ProductID])
INCLUDE ([StartDate],[EndDate])
```

OR

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Product
ON [dbo].[Test] ([ProductID], [StartDate])
INCLUDE ([EndDate])
```

OR

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Product
ON [dbo].[Test] ([ProductID],[EndDate])
INCLUDE ([StartDate])
```

If one of the dates gives good selectivity, then have an index on it instead of ProductID.

If none of the columns have good selectivity, then it is tough.

**Edit**

It is silly to blindly make an index as suggested by the optimizer, because you know that you will search for a particular ProductID, but then for a range of StartDates and then range of EndDates. So, the third column EndDate will never be used for the search itself. It this case it is better to `INCLUDE` this column in the index, rather than make it part of the index, as I've shown above.

If the query was for particular ProductID and for **particular** StartDate (not a range) and then for a range of EndDate (or particular EndDate), then having the EndDate as part of the index would help.

Comment: All that work and your conclusion is the suggested index is silly.  It is not silly.

Comment: @Blam, I've added my explanation to the answer why index suggested by optimizer is not a good idea.

Comment: Thank you for the followup explanation and generating this example.  I think the addition of the index on the ProductID first is clearly the way to go as it limits the search space significantly, and I'll have to think about the effectiveness of the composite key vs. the included column method. I may use your simulation to bump up the data to about 700K ProductIDs with time ranging over five years and then compare the performance between the two.  Your answer was very helpful, thanks!

Comment: BS  I tested.  Did you?  Index on int, date, date resulted in an index seek - you don't get better than that.

Comment: @Blam, of course, the operator in the plan is `index seek`. Go one step further and check the `seek predicate` and just `predicate` of this operator: right-click - Properties. In my test case the `seek predicate` is: `Seek Keys[1]: Prefix: [Test].ProductID = Scalar Operator((1)), End: [Test].StartDate <= Scalar Operator([@VarDate])`. Predicate is `[@VarDate]<=[EndDate]`. Which means that only two columns of the index are used for the seek itself. The condition for the third column `EndDate` (predicate) is evaluated for all rows found by the seek, as if the column was `INCLUDED` in the index.